# Why do I get "Servicve Temporary Unavailable" when I run my oracle forms on the IE once in a while?

Tags: oracle, internet-explorer

Once in a while that I run my Oracle forms 10g on IE, I get the following error:
   **"Service Temporary Unavailable"**
      The server is temporary unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or                                 capacity problems. Please try again later. 
Oracle application server 10g/10.1.2.2.0 Oracle http-server server at .....

has anyone faced this issue before?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error sounds fairly self-explanatory. If this is surprising for some reason, you might want to collect a network traffic log using Fiddler or similar to see if the server's HTTP/5xx response contains any additional information you could use for troubleshooting.